# Is it possible to train Tesseract 3.04 C# Wrapper? If so, how?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tesseract

I got this Tesseract Wrapper from https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract and it works just fine in VS2015. But I have some issues with the results.

So now I was wondering how this training for Tesseract 3.0x works and if it would work in the wrapper at all? Cause all I could found was this tutorial https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract which looks to be for Ubuntu only? Has someone experience with Tesseract training under c# in VS? Any tips how and where to start?